# Google Maps API - Polyline as image

Tags: google-maps

I need to get a static image of the route/path (polyline) in a map. 
I'm reading the Google Maps Static API docs here:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

But I can't find the option to request the API to get the path only, without the map in the background, the map needs to be transparent.

Comment: Hi! You can style your map and remove all routs , buldings etc. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/styling

Comment: @swativishnoi it need to be on server side, my client says the map is "too heavy" to be loaded in the app and requires the path only. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [***PATH*** parameter of Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#PathPoints).

Here is a sample request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Empire%20State%20Building&zoom=13&size=400x400&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963|40.752946,-73.987384|40.755823,-73.986397&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Hope this is the one you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you! It was not exactly what I needed but it was the way to go. I'll be sharing my solution soon.

Comment: @bmvr this is **not at all** what you asked for.